# how to declare variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one string variable that variable i used in all pages. So i decide we declare a class and i set the string as public. After i assign value for that variable in one place. 
 I retrieve the string variable in another page the value not come.
So i need how to use public variable.

```
Public Class Class1

    Shared _importantData As String
    Public Shared Property ImportantData As String
        Get
            Return _importantData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _importantData = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

In login page i assign value to public variable

```
Class1.ImportantData = "Data Source=" +  
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataSource").ToString +  
    ";Initial Catalog=" +  
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InitialCatalog").ToString + 
    ";User ID=" + Session("username") + ";Password=" +  
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Password").ToString + ""
```

In second page i retrieve the value like this

```
Dim comsd As String = Class1.ImportantData
```

Comment: Why don't you use the _connectionStrings_ section in your configuration with the whole string so you don't have to rebuild it every time

Comment: for our purpose user id is dynamic  so i need like this userid is get from when i enter in login form. So i need the public variable.